# How to use Emugu CV for Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding of an image?

Tags: c#, opencv, c#-4.0, image-processing, adaptive-threshold

I was going through the documentation of [Emugu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/8dee1f02-8c8a-4e37-87f4-05e10c39f27d.htm) but could not find which thing to use. Can someone show me some examples on how to use it for adaptive gaussian thresholding ?

Answer (score 2):

An example of Adaptive Gaussian thresholding

```
Image<Gray, byte> input;
Image<Gray, byte> output= input.ThresholdAdaptive(new Gray(255), Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ADAPTIVE_THRESHOLD_TYPE.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY , windowSize, new Gray(0.03));
```

hope this helps